# Bann one or more IP address with PHP withouthtaccess using .htaccess

Tags: php, ip, ip-address

I'm looking for good code in PHP for Banning some spammers IP's My server is giving me error 500 if I'm using  .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the work

```
$getip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 
$banned_ip = array(); 

$banned_ip[] = '194.9.94.*'; 
$banned_ip[] = '77.105.2.*'; 

foreach($banned_ip as $banned) 
{ 
$blacked=str_replace('*', '', $banned); 
$len=strlen($blacked); 
if ($getip==$blacked || substr($getip, 0, $len)==$blacked) 
{ 
$_banned_ip=true; 
} 
} 

if($_banned_ip==true){  
echo 'THIS IP IS BANNED!'; 
exit;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to have a database that keeps a list of the banned ip addresses, if you want to do it on the PHP end rather than directly in the server.

```
for($i = 0;$i < count($listOfIps);$i++) {
    if($listOfIps[$i] == filteredIP($_SERVER['REMOTED_ADDR'])) { //filteredIP is not a native function, it's just a representation of however you want to filter the ip addresses which are sent to you
        $banned = true;
    }
}

if($banned):
    //redirect user or kill script
else:
    //render page

endif;
```

However, there may be better solutions based on the page or application specifics, but this is the best solution I can think of based on your question